# Parse error due to incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets can't solve

Tags: haskell, indentation

So I am trying to create my own split function in Haskell and I keep getting a parse error but I can't figure out exactly why it is doing it

```
split :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
split _ [] = []
split x y = let
              test :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
              test x [] = []
              test x (y:ys) | x == y = []
                            | otherwise = y : (test x ys)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `let ... in` expression is missing the `in` part.